# How to revert a "git rm -r ."?

Tags: git, git-rm

I accidentely said `git rm -r .`. How do I recover from this?

I did not commit.

I think all files were marked for deletion and were also physically removed from my local checkout.

*EDIT:* I could (if I knew the command) revert to the last commit. But it would be a lot better if I could just undo the `git rm -r .`. Because I am not really sure what I did after the last commit and before the `git rm -r .`.

Comment: For this particular question, reset --hard is a good solution...it's already listed so I'll just mention in this comment that you might want to check the documentation for git-reflog.

Comment: Note that because you didn't supply `-f` to `git rm` git won't have removed any files that had staged or unstaged changes so a `git reset; git checkout .` should recover everything.

Comment: Just watch out - git checkout . will wipe out all unstaged changes.

Comment: I just did something like this, and I do not understand why my local files where deleted (and, like the OP, I have not committed yet.)

Comment: With Git 2.23+ (August 2019), you would restore files with `git restore`: `git restore -s@ -SW -- .`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58753735/6309).

Answer (score 546, accepted):

```
git reset HEAD
```

Should do it. If you don't have any uncommitted changes that you care about, then

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

should forcibly reset everything to your last commit. If you do have uncommitted changes, but the first command doesn't work, then save your uncommitted changes with `git stash`:

```
git stash
git reset --hard HEAD
git stash pop
```

Comment: Note that `git reset --hard HEAD` destroys any useful changes you have made in parent directories of the current working directory.

Comment: @Mild: I'm still wearing a cold sweat!

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I just tried stash, reset hard, pop and lost all of my recent changes. Maybe I misread the answer.

Comment: This rarely works for me, and I'm so glad I work in a Dropbox folder. Poor form, but saves me every time...

Comment: When I did git stash pop, it just removed the files again, of course because it stashes the fact that I (accidentally) removed some files. This answer doesn't work if you have uncommited changes you want to keep.

Comment: This also did not work for me. The files are still missing.

Comment: This does not answer the question. `git rm -r .` could be executed in any sub-directly. This will reset the entire tree. See @Jaime Bellmyer answer.

Comment: You may need `git stash -u`/`git stash --include-untracked` if your recent changes include new (untracked) files.

Comment: @sudo Instead of using `git stash pop` you can use `git stash apply`. This way if there's a merge conflict or you want to discard the changes without them being removed from the top of the stash.

Comment: `git stash;
git reset --hard HEAD;
git stash pop` Did the trick for me! Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't help in any way.

Comment: `git checkout HEAD .` recovered all my folders and files.

Comment: This solution does not work. Popping the stash back leads to untracked but still deleted files and folders. 
The following two options work -- 

(1) `git stash; git reset HEAD; git stash drop 0` (here you are stashing the deleted files/folders and resetting to head and then dropping your stash with deleted changes) 

(2) `git checkout HEAD .`

Comment: i really made a huge mistake

Comment: If you can read this, be calm.
Backup everything before trying any of those git commands.

Comment: If you have already committed, try `git reset HEAD~n`. (n is the number of how many previous commits you want to go backward. You can also use `^` together with `~` for better control.)

Answer (score 293):

I git-rm'd a few files and went on making changes before my next commit when I realized I needed some of those files back. Rather than stash and reset, you can simply checkout the individual files you missed/removed if you want:

```
git checkout HEAD path/to/file path/to/another_file
```

This leaves your other uncommitted changes intact with no workarounds.

Comment: This helped because I had other uncommitted changes.

Comment: This answer helps for those of us that stumbled upon this question looking to revert a single `git rm` rather than an entire recursive `git rm -r`.  For a full recursive delete, the other solutions may be better, depending on the amount of files removed.

Answer (score 72):

To regain some single files or folders one may use the following

```
git reset -- path/to/file
git checkout -- path/to/file
```

This will first recreate the index entries for `path/to/file` and recreate the file as it was in the last commit, i.e.`HEAD`.

**Hint:** one may pass a commit hash to both commands to recreate files from an older commit. See `git reset --help` and `git checkout --help` for details.

Comment: Best answer.  Easy surgical 'undo' of a single `git rm` operation without wiping out other uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 38):

**undo git rm**

```
git rm file             # delete file & update index
git checkout HEAD file  # restore file & index from HEAD
```

**undo git rm -r**

```
git rm -r dir          # delete tracked files in dir & update index
git checkout HEAD dir  # restore file & index from HEAD
```

---

**undo git rm -rf**

```
git rm -r dir          # delete tracked files & delete uncommitted changes
not possible           # `uncommitted changes` can not be restored.
```

`Uncommitted changes` includes `not staged changes`, `staged changes but not committed`.

Comment: Of course, nothing can undo `git rm -rf`, as that may delete untracked or staged (only) files as well.

Comment: `git rm -rf file` and `git rm -rf dir` will not delete any untracked files.

Answer (score 33):

Update:

Since `git rm .` deletes all files in this and child directories in the working checkout as well as in the index, you need to undo each of these changes:

```
git reset HEAD . # This undoes the index changes
git checkout .   # This checks out files in this and child directories from the HEAD
```

This should do what you want.  It does not affect parent folders of your checked-out code or index.

---

Old answer that wasn't:

```
reset HEAD
```

will do the trick, and *will not erase any uncommitted changes* you have made to your files.

after that you need to repeat any `git add` commands you had queued up.

Comment: sorry, I always setup `git alias.co="checkout"` so that `git co` does checkout.

Answer (score 30):

If you end up with none of the above working, you might be able to retrieve data using the suggestion from here: http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg62499.html

```
git prune -n
git cat-file -p <blob #>
```

Comment: 4 years later, still a lifesaver!

Comment: I wrote a c++ program to concatenate the results (I had some 100 objects dangling in my repo, making this necessary). Just compile and run, then pass in your git repo local directory. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bluuman/git-recover-files/master/main.cpp

Comment: This is a good method, after running the `git prune -n`, I got many lines, those lines are either `tree` or `blob` or `commit`, and I fill out all the hash string of `blob`, and I try to use the second command to `git cat-file -p <blob #>`, and I still can't find the lost file. My situation is quite simple, I have create a new file named `a.cpp`, and I add this file to the index, and later I use the `git rm -f` to remove this file, and I see that `a.cpp` get lost.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment, I tested again, it can recover the `git rm -f` deleted file, I'm not sure why the previous test does not works, thanks!

Comment: Just a note that while this works, it cannot recover filenames or paths, so if you're like me and you just deleted a 5k file nested folder system you were trying to create a repo for, you are basically completely out of luck.

Answer (score 13):

If you've committed and pushed the changes, you can do this to get the file back

```
// Replace 2 with the # of commits back before the file was deleted.
git checkout HEAD~2 path/to/file
```

Comment: This worked for 'Changes to be committed:' where a file was deleted from an old git cherry-pick which I still needed.I had tried git reset HEAD~<number> <file> which didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

There are some good answers already, but I might suggest a little-used syntax that not only works great, but is very explicit in what you want (therefor not scary or mysterious)

```
git checkout <branch>@{"20 minutes ago"} <filename>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you execute the command `git rm -r --cached .` on a repo with changes that are not staged (so not committed either), you can undo the operation (unstage from deletion) with the command `git restore --staged .`

So in a nutshell, to **undo** `git rm -r --cached .` you only need to run `git restore --staged .`

Comment: This worked for me luckily before I did a commit but for clarity you have to append the file that you removed to the end as in: `git restore --staged completePathToRemovedFile`

Answer (score 3):

Get list commit

```
git log  --oneline
```

For example, Stable commit has hash: `45ff319c360cd7bd5442c0fbbe14202d20ccdf81`

```
git reset --hard 45ff319c360cd7bd5442c0fbbe14202d20ccdf81
git push -ff origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

With Git 2.23+ (August 2019), the proper command to restore files (and the index) woud be to use... **[`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)** (not `reset --hard` or the [confusing `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

That is:

```
git restore -s=HEAD --staged --worktree -- .
```

Or its abbreviated form:

```
git restore -s@ -SW -- .
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an identical situation. In my case the solution was:

```
git checkout -- .
```

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue: was cleaning up my folders, rearranging and moving files. I entered: git rm *.* and hit enter; and then felt my bowels loosen a bit. Luckily, I didn't type in git commit -m "" straightaway.

However, the following command

```
git checkout .
```

restored everything, and saved my life.