# How can I recover from deleting the .git directory?

Tags: git

I didn't realize all my files were stored and attached to the .git repository. I just thought I was deleting .git's version of the proj. I did a

```
rm -fr .git
```

I lost all my work! What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r

Comment: Did you run `git rm -fr` or did you run `rm -fr .git`? One is a git command, the other is a shell command.

Comment: More importantly, `git rm -fr` is not a disaster :)

Comment: I edited the question to Cameron Skinner's second option; that seems to be what you did.

Comment: I think the moral of this story is that version control and backups are not the same thing. Both are important. If you keep a remote git repository somewhere (like github) then git can do both, but they are two different things.

Comment: See this topic : [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246907/can-deleted-git-be-restored

Answer (score 0):

You can check out a new copy of the repository from any remote copy. If you have shared your work with any other developers (i.e. anyone has `pull`ed from your repository or you have `push`ed into theirs), or if you have your own "master" repository then you should be OK.

You should still have your working copy if the .git directory was the only thing you deleted. All your history will be gone but at least your code won't be.

If this really was the only copy of your work then you may be out of luck, sorry. Unless your filesystem has an "undelete" option (which it probably does not if you're on Linux).

Comment: Gosh I'm so dumb... I didn't have a copy. I'm going to look into data recovery.. any suggestions? (snow leopard on a mac)

Comment: Do you still have the working copy, i.e. everything except the .git directory?

Comment: Look a testdisk for data recovery.  I've had success with it in the past.  It's a free command line tool.

Comment: Sorry, scratch that.  Testdisk can't get deleted files from HFS+.

Comment: This might be obvious, but if you're using Snow Leopard, were you using Time Machine?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever push your changes to another repository (i.e. github.com, or somebody else on your team?).  Git is distributed, which means things like this should not matter.  Just 'git clone' a fresh copy from somewhere that still exists.

If your Git repository was only ever stored in the one place and you'd never pushed it (or originally pulled it) to/from another location, you're out of luck, buddy ;)  You still have your working tree, so the best you'll do is to 'git init' and start a new repo from what you currently have.

Sounds like you need to read up on git... that fact that everything lives in the '.git' directory is perhaps one of the most basic aspects to understanding git.

http://www.gitready.com/