# Deleted .git in my home directory on mac

Tags: git, macos

I did

```
rm -R .git
```

in a Folder that didn't exist any more. It asked me this:

```
override r--r--r--  myuser/staff for .git/objects/pack/pack-1b49dfb11db4715dfac10c4bf1540bf7272fe2e9.idx? ^C
```

Here I realised that I did something wrong. So I hit ctrl+C.

I am not sure what happened but as a result none of my local git repos are operational anymore

```
➜  some-project git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
➜  some-project git --version
git version 2.9.3 (Apple Git-75)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can deleted .git be restored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246907/can-deleted-git-be-restored)

Comment: "I am not sure what happened" What happened is that you said `rm -R .git`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-clone back to this directory.

- backup your current work
- git clone `your git url` `your git directory`