# Git repository similar to local, how to merge

Tags: git, github

I don't know exactly how to put it but here is my problem:
I have a git repository related to laravel project. I also have the same folder on local but i deleted the .git folder, .gitignore and .gitattrib files, i.e. my local folder is no longer connected to github. Now i have made changes to local files and want to push those to the original repository. How can i do that?

Comment: How many files have you changed?  The quick and dirty approach might be to clone that repository again, and then overwrite the files you've modified with your versions.

Comment: You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6246975/5085788), specifically the part of **uncommited changes**.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to simply commit your changes as a new commit in your repository:

1. Ensure you have a clone of your repository locally

   If needs be, reclone it, or if you already have one you can most
   likely reuse that clone.
2. Make sure you're on the right branch in that clone

   If needs be, create and checkout a new branch for the modifications
   that you did locally while "unconnected to GitHub".
3. Then bring those changes into your working folder of the clone

   Basically, copy **from** the local, "unconnected" folder
   ... and copy **to** the working folder of your repository

   **Note!** If any of your "local changes" involved deleting or
   moving file you need to ensure you do the same thing in your
   working folder.

   If you got any kind of directory comparison tool, such as
   [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/), then
   you should use this to ensure you synchronize not just file
   contents but also directory **structure**.
4. Then all you have to do is commit your modified files into your repository

   1. Do a `git status` to ensure everything looks good
   2. Do a `git status --ignored` to ensure git won't ignore any files you care about
   3. Do a `git add .` to stage your modifications
   4. Do a `git commit` to commit your changes
5. Verify everything looks good

   Do a build, whatever
6. Merge your changes into your main branch (develop or master or whatever)