# Gitignore does not ignore files listed

Tags: git

After cloning my repository (I am working on Magento customization) I have edited an old `.gitignore` bad written file with a correct `.gitignore` taken from [here.](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Magento.gitignore)

Then, noticing that Git was tracking also files supported to be ignored I would try to list the ignored files by Git.

I've tried to do:

> git clean -ndX

as far as

> git status --ignored

and the result is always the same : `no output` .

I have to suppose that NOT ANY file is ignored by Git at the moment in my repository and I am stuck and tired to look for documentation.

Could anybody kindly help?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for grammatical errors, its late and i am tired.

Answer (score 1):

`.gitignore` doesn't apply to files already in the repository. (It sounds like you have some files you actually want to remove from the repository?) If you want to ignore future changes to an already tracked file, you need to use `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) documentation you'll find your answer almost immediately.

> Files already tracked by Git are not affected...

`git clean` only applies to files that are not tracked as well.

If you want to remove the files that are already in the repository, but now should be ignored you can run the [following command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7076075/2158473) -

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-standard`
```

This will leave the files in place, but remove them from the index.