# Git ignore shell scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

Hi I am using git version 2.1.0 in my rails application . I want to ignore shell script from a folder called services

```
/services/*.sh
```

I have used this code in .gitignore ,  but it doesn’t works.I have called a single file directly too like

```
/services/setup_env_local.sh
```

its also not works .But other extensions like .log , .rb are ignoring with the same code

```
/services/*.log
```

what is the mistake I have done?...

Comment: Did you earlier commit this `setup_env_local.sh` into your repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in the root of the git directory called `.gitignore` and add the line `/services/*.sh` to it. This should work.

Comment: I already have a gitignore file, my question is only the shell scripts are not ignored why..

Comment: maybe this is your issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075923/resync-git-repo-with-new-gitignore-file

Comment: @Navin I tested this locally on my machine and *.sh files are ignored the same as all other file types.

Comment: @Navin gitignore will only ignore if the files are untracked if your file is already tracked by git then gitignore will not have any effect on it.