# Git - undoing git rm

Tags: git, git-rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert a “git rm -r .”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r)

Git SOS here. I worked 10 hours on a project without committing (I know, I know) and then I git added too many files, so I tried using git rm and accidentally deleted EVERYTHING. Is there hope for me? :(((

Answer (score 183, accepted):

If you already commited changes, then:

```
git reset (--hard) HEAD~1
```

If not then:

```
git reset
git ls-files -d -z | xargs -0 git checkout --
```

Comment: Would `git reset --hard HEAD` work in the second case?

Comment: Will, but it will also discard all your changes.

Comment: Ah, ok. What exactly is the second line doing here? Is it strictly undoing the rm, or does it have a wider effect?

Comment: It remove all files in index and then checkout all modified files to HEAD.

Comment: Be careful when using the second one, I tried using it to recover some accidentally rm'd files and lost my uncommitted changes. Noob mistake I guess.

Comment: To restore deleted files the last part should look like `git ls-files -d` and thet it will recover only deleted files.

Comment: I lost all my uncommited changes after `git checkout -- $(git ls-files -m)`. I don't know if what other people are commenting here is right (using `git ls-files -d` instead), but someone who knows should edit this answer

Comment: `git checkout -- $(git ls-files -d)` This doesn't work if the filenames have spaces in them

Comment: `git ls-files -d -z | xargs -0 git checkout --` is the way to go for the generic case with filename spaces (http://jennyandlih.com/using-git-ls-files-input-xargs)

Comment: install trash and then `alias rm=trash` in `.zshrc` or similar, now all deletes are undo able :)

Comment: Is `xargs` only for linux?  How can I do the same thing from the Windows command line?