# Any way to recover from `git rm * -r -f` if no commits were made?

Tags: git

I don't know if this is the best place to ask it, but I have a serious problem.

I've worked 3 months on a project. And planned to go to GIT.

I did a `git init`, a month back. A few days after the init I've renamed the project.

After that I accidentally did these commands.

`git rm * -r -f` - Because some 'deletes' weren't staged for commit
`git reset --hard` - Because I thought I was able to reset to before the `git rm`.

I didn't know that git was able to remove files and haven't committed anything.

Am I able to get my files back, and how?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: have your deleted files been committed at some point?

Comment: @DaveHarding I've edited it. `Am I able to get my files back, and how?`

Comment: @njzk2 No, I've never did a `git commit`

Comment: If you never did a commit then they're gone

Comment: @WesHardaker Why doesn't GIT use the trash bin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698978/git-undoing-git-rm

Comment: If your files where never committed, then they are lost.

Comment: @user3489690 there is no such thing as a "trash bin" in a normal file system, those are features of specific OSs or desktop environments.

Comment: If you `git add`-ed various files, you may be able to get them back, but they will have funny names (SHA-1 names).  That might still be useful.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9928789/1256452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @torek and [Recover dangling blobs in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git/9928789#9928789). I've got my files back!

I did a `git fsck --lost-found` and all my files were in `.git/lost-found/other`

I've created a new xcode project and after one hour of work, everything is working again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you never committed anything, the files are gone.

You can confirm this using `git reflog` and verifying that no commits were ever made.

The reflog for an empty repository looks like this:

```
$ git reflog
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

as opposed to a repository with a single commit:

```
$ git reflog
a1b2c3d HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): Initial commit
```

Comment: Reflog only shows the initial commit which was made 1 month ago

Comment: Then sorry mate. Anything that isn't in the reflog is unrecoverable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an IDE like Eclipse that has a local history, you can try that (restore from local history).
If you had something like a maven build that also generated a sources jar, then you can try it as well.

Otherwise, sorry your files are gone.
Next time: commit early, commit often.

Comment: I don't know xcode - but you can try undo. Check if you have a time machine configured as well (or any other sort of backup).

Comment: The phrase "commit early, commit often" deserves to be in *every* git manual!

Comment: @RolandSmith and its variations in every source control manual!