# How to un-delete a file using git?

Tags: git

This morning, I logged into my production server and accidentally delete one of my file.

`UrlController.php`

Unfortunately, there is no undo in WinSCP.
As soon as you hit on the red `X`, it gone for good.

Fortunately, I use git.
When I do `git status`, this is what I see.

[image]

Is there anywhere to use git to bring that file back, or undo what I just delete ?

I'm new to git. Feel free to suggest a better option.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to undelete files in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564256/how-to-undelete-files-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ git checkout app/controllers/UrlController.php
```

Comment: after doing git checkout, what else should I do ?

Comment: @evoque2015 That should undo the deletion completly, so there is nothing further to be done.

Comment: I always use `git checkout -- <filename>` to distinguish it from any other `git checkout` commands.

Comment: @Agis : It's work. So `checkout` will always bring back the file ? just curious ...