# revert git rm -rf in just inititlized repo.

Tags: git

What I did is as follows:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
# bunch of unwanted files were also added
$ vim .gitignore
$ git rm -rf *
$ git add .
# but the files were actually deleted from the ./ folder.
```

Now what i have in the directory are only the .gitignore pattern files. All the necessary files are gone.

As mentioned in this post [How to revert a "git rm -r ."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r/14415549)

is `git reset HEAD` way to go?

I am not sure i should run this command as i have not made any commits till now.

Comment: `git reset HEAD` says unknown revision

Comment: `git log` to see you init commit SHA and then `git checkout <SHA>` ?

Comment: `git log` ==> `fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `git fsck --lost-found`:

```
$ mkdir tt
$ cd tt
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo I am foo > foo
$ echo I am bar > bar
$ git add .
$ git rm -rf *
rm 'bar'
rm 'foo'
$ git fsck --lost-found
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
dangling blob 2adbcadb36527b3048a96c5bad232f6c9e762524
dangling blob bea14010b78ced155c64da9a4c2b1a6b0831335e
$ ls .git/lost-found/other/
2adbcadb36527b3048a96c5bad232f6c9e762524
bea14010b78ced155c64da9a4c2b1a6b0831335e
$ cat .git/lost-found/other/2adbcadb36527b3048a96c5bad232f6c9e762524 
I am foo
```

The file's *names* are gone, but all their *contents* are restored, to their hash-ID based names.

Comment: Needn't restart a week of work. :) it worked. I was looking through the files in the .git directory, but the lost-found appears only after the `git fsck` command.

Comment: Yes - before that, these "dangling blob"s are in the .git/objects/ directory and are in compressed, Git-ified form.

Comment: After trying various 'undelete'-tools for linux this was the only possible and working solution for me.