# undo git rm on a newly created file

Tags: git

I create a new file (let's call it myfile.txt) and added some content to it. Then I decided to delete it using `git rm` command. Later I realized I shouldn't have deleted the file. Is there a way to get it back? Please note that I haven't added or commited the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert a "git rm -r ."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r)

Comment: You didn't `git add` or `commit` the file?

Comment: @Daniel that one from my understanding refers to previously commmited file where in my case I haven't added or commited the file

Comment: @cricket_007 no I didn't

Comment: As far as I know, `git rm` does not delete files. It only untracks them. Which, you didn't track them, so therefore, it's not clear how the file was removed

Comment: @cricket_007 By default, `git rm` both untracks and deletes files. It's the first line in the docs "*git-rm - Remove files from the working tree and from the index*". If you only want to untrack it's `git rm --cached`.

Comment: @Schwern Hmm. Maybe it's in my git config not to delete, because I just tried it, and the file was not deleted

Comment: @Dmitry If you never `git add`ed the file, then you should not have been able to `git rm` it. You should have gotten `fatal: pathspec 'myfile.txt' did not match any files`. If you did `git add` it, you should have gotten something like `error: the following file has changes staged in the index: myfile.txt`. Can you show exactly what you actually did? Perhaps by running `history`?

Answer (score 0):

It confuses your question a bit. If you executed git rm on the file, it means that you previously followed it.
It can help you see the log of that file specifically to be sure:

```
git log --follow -- myfile.txt
```

You can use the last commit of the log to restore it

```
git checkout <commit-sha-1> -- myfile.txt
```

however, if you never committed the file it is impossible to recover it, at least with Git

I hope that helps