# How do I recover all the files that were removed with git rm

Tags: git

I was playing around with git, I'm not really good with it, I know a little bit about it and while i was trying to make the .gitignore work on a different branch so I issued

```
$ git rm -r --cached .
fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files
```

So I was looking for some options for git rm , I accidentally pressed enter and typed `git rm`, and now almost all the files that I've been working on for months are now gone, how will I recover it back?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, reset the HEAD.

`git reset HEAD`

I just found similar question. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r) for more explanation.

Comment: I am stuck on a different branch and not in the master ? Should I continue it ?

Comment: Yes, refer this question for more explanation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r

Answer (score 0):

On your current branch, where you have done the `rm`, the more modern way to restore your files would be using [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) (Git 2.23+):

```
git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree -- .
```

Comment: sadly I'm on a git 2.18 version

Comment: @TheBAST Can you upgrade? If not, I will leave the answer for future reader.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for few minutes, will that not make damage to my files ? like upgrading the git ?

Comment: @TheBAST no it will not. But in your case, try first the other solutions, based on reset or checkout.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/C2jbzuvz

Comment: @TheBAST How would that pastbin session, regarding the checkout of the `offer-bounty` branch, be related to your current issue?